# How to reassign an array value in a loop?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a following piece of code:-

```
$returnArr = $this->master_model->fetch_all_data($data, $selectString,$limit, $offset);
foreach($returnArr as $row)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($data.'_image', $row)) 
        {
            $img = base_url()."uploads/$data/". $row[$data.'_image'];
            $row[$data.'_image'] = $img;
        }
    }
print_r($returnArr);
```

The $return is in the following format:

```
Array ( [0] => 
         Array ( [sticker_image] => post_1462515402.jpg 
                 [sticker_code] => :* ) 
        [1] => Array ( [sticker_image] => post_1462515510.jpg 
                 [sticker_code] => ^=^ ) 
        [2] => Array ( [sticker_image] => post_1462515532.jpg 
                 [sticker_code] => >_<* ) 
        [3] => Array ( [sticker_image] => post_1462515539.jpg 
                 [sticker_code] => :(( ) )
```

Now, in the following line of code, I am changing [sticker_image] to a link:

```
if (array_key_exists($data.'_image', $row)) 
{
    $img = base_url()."uploads/$data/". $row[$data.'_image'];
    $row[$data.'_image'] = $img;
}
```

Still, the changes doesn't take place. It's still coming as

```
[sticker_image] => post_1462515402.jpg
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May be it is not going inside the `array_key_exists($data.'_image', $row)`. The question will be unclear without knowing the values of the other variable.

Comment: @Daan Er... What? :P

Answer (score 1):

`$row[$data.'_image'] = $img;` will change only local copy of array element.

To change actual array element you must loop with reference:

```
$returnArr = ['a' => 'b'];

foreach ($returnArr as &$row) {
    $row = 'cc';
}

var_dump($returnArr); // ['a' => 'cc'];
```